# Create a template file for view field?

Tags: views, theming

How do I create template file for view field, My view machine name is *page_search* and field name is *room type*.

Comment: This links is lead you correctly 
https://api.drupal.org/api/views/theme!theme.inc/group/views_templates/7

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9914220/how-to-theme-views-fields-in-drupal-7-correctly

**before ask a question please search for it maybe previously answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First look into Theme information in views:

[image]

- In Row style output, copy one of the template names:

[image]

- This lists all available **.tpl for your views** and now Create an empty php file with your chosen template name in your **themes template folder**.